# How do you upload artifacts in nexus via the file system

Tags: maven, nexus

I am running nexus 2.9.1.02 to host artifacts for maven builds. I would like to load artifacts via the file system. I do not want to use the web UI. Instead, just putting the folders with required pom and jar files in the sonatype-work/nexus/storage folder.

After loading the files into the file system, the artifacts show up in the "browse storage" tab. However, they do not show up in the "browse index" tab and Maven can not download them.

Is it possible to load artifacts via the file system only? How do you sync the file system to the repo database/indexing?

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: Have you tried the re-index option via the web UI?

Comment: If you add artifacts directly on the file system level you need to do reindex the artifacts otherwise Nexus does not know anything about the new artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can place artifacts directly into local storage.  See here for tasks you will need to run after doing this:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/38605563-Can-I-directly-update-artifacts-in-Nexus-local-storage-on-disk-

Answer (score 3):

There's a way to do this that should be repository agnostic.  Use the mvn [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) plugin.  Here's an example:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
-DrepositoryId=repoId
-Durl=repoUrl
-Dfile=pathToFile
-DgroupId=groupId
-DartifactId=artifactId
-Dversion=versionNumber 
-DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: For this question, I am not adding artifacts that are part of a maven build. I am just trying to host dependencies that are not in any public maven repo. But, I will need this once I start deploying my artifacts.

Comment: @NathanReese This doesn't have to be part of a maven build.  You specify that file with `-Dfile=`